# Write the negation:

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Write a negation of the following statement without using words of negation:
A bounded real function cannot be surjective."
Which is true, the statement, or its negation? Justify your answer.

ATTEMPT: An unbounded real function can be surjective. And for the second part I think the negation is True since if a function is bounded, how can it ever reach all the elements in the real numbers due to its restrictions.

Am I right?

Comment: You are not right. You did not negate the statement correctly.

Comment: HINT: Why did you did change it to "unbounded".

Comment: Recall that the negation of $p \to q$ is p AND not q.

Answer (score -1):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. Your statement can be write as follow:

$$\exists M>0\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}(|f(x)|<M\Rightarrow \exists a\in\mathbb{R} \ \forall y\in\mathbb{R},\ f(y)\neq a)$$ 
then the negation (accordingly to the logic rules) is:

$$\exists M>0\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}(|f(x)|<M\ \wedge\ \forall a\in\mathbb{R} \ \exists y\in\mathbb{R},\ f(y)= a).$$

Comment: And the first statement is correct. Therefore the second is false.